# Recovery scenario in QTP not invoked from script

Tags: qtp

I've written the following code for attaching my recovery scenario with script during run time. It is as follows:

```
Dim App
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Enabled = True
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.SetActivationMode "OnEveryStep"
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Add "C:\QTP\Recovery\Navigation.qrs", "Navigation", 1
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Item(1).Enabled = True
Recovery.Activate
App.Test.Save
```

The recovery scenario is not invoked.

Is the code correct? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** The recovery scenario gets added to the script (i.e., can be seen in `File->Settings->Recovery`) but it is not being invoked. But if we run it for the second time, it gets invoked.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom:  This is expected behavior. You cannot dynamically load Recovery Scenarios and use them at runtime. Once it is associated though (manually or programmatically), the next time you run the script, it will be fired.